# Asp net grid view select row using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a normal gridview on asp.net web page... I want to select a row using jquery and then pressing a button to send the id and descripcion columns to a web service...

My question is how can I select the row and get the information I want... all using jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
$('#<%=Grid.ClientID %>').delegate('tr', 'click', function(){
    $('#<%=Grid.ClientID %> tr').not(this).removeClass('selectedRow');
    $(this).toggleClass('selectedRow'); 
});
```

This should enable you to select a single GridView row on click.

After that, for the button control, use the following

```
$('#<%=Btn.ClientID %>').click(function(){
    alert($('#<%=Grid.ClientID %>').find('tr.selectedRow').html());

    // code to call the webservice using columns from $('#<%=Grid.ClientID %>').find('tr.selectedRow')

    // prevent Button control from causing a postback
    return false;
});
```