# Selecting a Gridview row without a select column in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, gridview, row

Im a newbie and totally new in ASP.NET. I need to select a row in a gridview by just clicking a row in it and not by clicking a select button from a select row column.
Thanks :)

Comment: Let the javascript do the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use jQuery for this. 
 Here is a good example 
[Asp net grid view select row using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355889/asp-net-grid-view-select-row-using-jquery)

Here too is a good example 
http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/324_Make_GridView_Row_Selectable_or_Clickable_using_jQuery_in_ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your code to make the any cells of any row selectable.

```
//Select a row by clicking any cells of it
        protected void grdEmployeeList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
                e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";

                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdEmployeeList, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            }
        }
```

and then add this page attribute to the first line of the source code of the page designer:

```
EnableEventValidation = "false"
```

FYI the grid specified in the above code refers to my gridview object.

Just fill in the GridView with your Rows and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. You don't want to click select button so make your data in the grid a link button to show the data as well as click on it. Following is the code for the same

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CODE" ShowHeader="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="td" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_header"
                                ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderColor="LightGray" HeaderStyle-Width="10%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCode" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("Amm_code") %>' CommandName="Select"
                                        ForeColor="Blue" ToolTip="Click To Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="td" />
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="td" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```